# Why test class is not covered in FOR loop?

Tags: apex, unit-test

It's covered only 45%. Could you please help me?

Comment: first query your recordType based on developername=Revenue and assign that recordType id to OpportunitySplit.recordTypeId

Comment: @Ratan, I tired, not working. Could you send me exact code for that.

Comment: `RecordType obj= [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'OpportunitySplit' AND DeveloperName = 'Revenue' LIMIT 1];`  then use this recordType Id in `OpportunitySplit os = new OpportunitySplit(); os.RecordTypeId = obj.Id;`

Comment: check in query you are getting record. Also you are using `OPPIDSET` first after that adding value. Don't understand the reason.

Comment: @Ratan - That recordtypeID is not there in OpportunitySplit. Its showing an error.

Comment: @VivekanandaReddy sorry it is `OpportunitySplitType`

Comment: Could you please anyone optimise this test class and also it will be cover 75%. Please send me that code here.

Comment: People are not here to do your work for you. We're all giving you pointers as to what is wrong with your code and trying to help you understand the issues and fix them yourself

Comment: @mkorman - Hey Man, I am asking help. Already I tired 45% coverd my test class.

Comment: Why don't you try some of the help that users have posted below? There's a couple of good ideas for you to work on. It would be nice if you tried their suggestions and posted a comment as a response :)

Answer (score 1):

If I closely Observe your code -

```
List<OpportunitySplit> opportunitySplitData = new List<OpportunitySplit>([SELECT OpportunityId,Opportunity.OwnerId,SplitOwnerId,SplitPercentage,SplitType.DeveloperName from OpportunitySplit where OpportunityId in :oppIds and SplitOwner.Name!='Default Credit Split Account' order by SplitPercentage DESC NULLS FIRST limit 10000] );
```

This line gets the Opportunity Split data on the basis of **OppIds** set which you are setting later. So apparently the set is blank and the query returns no rows. You should be setting value in set before you query opportunity split. So I see you need to fix the class, test class looks ok.

I would run the business functionality again to see if it works as expected. Because, from code it looks skeptical.

Comment: Actually the tests are supposed to surface those errors

Comment: Mate, I did not get you. But if test class are supposed to surface those errors, it is already doing it by not covering those lines :)

Comment: Well, the way to surface those errors is to create Asserts and watch them fail. That's an explicit way of catching them.

Comment: Ok. I agree :) From the best practice standpoint, you are correct. Actually I still see the main issue is in his Apex Class, he tries to get spilt from OpportunityId set but there are no Opportunities in the set when query is made.

Comment: I agree that the issue may be in the 'production' code. That's what test code is for. He should create a test to assert that he's getting the right Opportunities in the set, instead of just aiming for test coverage...

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the test is to assert that your behaviour is correct, not to cover the lines of code (which is useless).

You're pasting a very long wall of text without a single assertion, which makes it very hard for the readers here to try and understand what is wrong.

Instead of writing a single test case that tries to cover 100% of your class, I would suggest writing several smaller tests in one class, each of them covering one condition (what happens when there is no opportunity split? what happens when there are no project engineers? what happens when there are no sales reps).

The fact that you're trying to do everything in one go makes it hard for everybody else to help.

I see a couple things wrong in your code which could lead to this:

- you're hard-coding values in your production code (`'Default Credit Split Account'`)
- you're hard-coding ID's in your test (`os.SplitOwnerId = '00560000002OwWG';`). There is no guarantee that the ID's will be there, so this may be breaking the test code
- you have no asserts!

I would go back to the drawing board, start little by little with your test class, writing small methods to assert that each small feature in your class work. If necessary, break down each feature in small methods. That will expose the error itself (either in production or test code).